# Is there a lightweight way to scan a static path for files from a chrome or firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I'm trying to implement a chrome or firefox extension, that basicly scans a static path on my hard drive for a file matching content from the matched html page. I know about File System Access API, but it's unconvenient for this use-case, since i don't see how someone can be asked for the directory only once.
I know that direct filesystem access is basically impossible (unless i want to use my browser with security features disabled or some other risky hacks).
I know it would be possible, if i setup a database with a web-app as an interface.
However, i think building something like a webserver, that serves as an interface to a database that is somehow updated with the file metadata is somewhat overengineered. I would consider it, if i could implement a lightweight solution, however i'm a windows user and i don't want to setup a whole xampp or dedicated raspberry system.

I'm open for any ideas.

Comment: Write a separate utility and run it from the extension via nativeMessaging API.

Comment: You can also enable file access checkbox in chrome://extensions page for your extension and fetch('file:///C:/Users/') then parse the result as html and extract the names.

Comment: Oh great! I thought nativeMessaging was for tcp/ip connections for some reason... Thank you very much :)